# Wordpress - apply custom CSS to backend

Tags: html, css, wordpress, customization

Recently I'm developing some basic websites, sometimes not-so-basic.
Anyway, I'm customizing wordpress, And I'm trying to achieve 100% wysiwyg.
I'm very close to do it, however, there's one style I cannot fix.

It is related to tinymce plugin. Size of text area is fine now, however I am not able to modify style for pictures.
There aare classes .alignleft and .alignright.

I've managed to include my custom.css (which is applied, and visible for firefox, I can see it properly loaded into FF inspector - Style editor tab), however style is not applied for selected elements.
It still applies rules from wp-content.css. I believe it is related to rules overlapping, and then wp-content as it's loaded later it overwrites my custom style. 
When I inspect this specific element, there's no entry from my custom.css (I mean the inspector tab).

Does anyone know how to solve it, or came into similiar issue?
I've tried plugins to niclude custom css for admin, etc. It seems to work fine to include my css, but styles are not applied.

If i'm not clear on some part, please ask questions I will provide screenshots.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of check they css comes from our local source or call some cdn source so css is called on other server. first of verify it

Comment: if the styles do not appear in dev tools ( even with line-through )  then the css file is not loaded properly.

Comment: Are the styles not applying in the editor or are the styles not applying on the site? If it is the former, you may want to take a look at this: https://torquemag.io/2016/09/add-custom-styles-wordpress-editor-manually-via-plugin/ (or search for a more up to date version)

Comment: Thanks guys for your answer, I think I was not understood correctly, Therefore I'm posting you a picture with the problem
[link]https://i.imgur.com/D71DU2m.png

Answer (score 0):

your CSS is bad.  you wrote `img .alignleft` which would apply to something nested inside the image tag that had a class of `alignleft` instead of an image with the class of `alignleft`. what you need is `img.alignleft`.

TLDR:  remove the space between `img` and the class

Comment: you'll also wantot addd rules for images with captions which would be `.alignleft img`